# jinja2: How to make it fail Silently like djangotemplate

Tags: python, django-templates, jinja2

Well i don't find the answer I'm sure that it's very simple, but i just don't find out how to make it work like Django when it doesn't find a variable

i tried to use Undefined and create my own undefined but it give me problems of attribute error etc.

```
def silently(*args, **kwargs):
    return u''

class UndefinedSilently(Undefined):
    __unicode__ = silently
    __str__ = silently
    __call__ = silently
    __getattr__ = silently
```

but when i try this here it fails `TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable`:

```
{%for dir_name, links in menu_links.items()%}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to go arbitrarily deep into your undefined data. `menu_links` is undefined, so Jinja2 creates a new instance of your `UndefinedSilently` class.  It then calls the `__getattr__` method of this object to get the `items` attribute.  This returns a blank unicode string.  Which Python then tries to call (the `()` of `menu_links.items()`).  Which raises the error that unicode objects are not callables.

That is:

```
menu_links.items() # becomes
UndefinedSilently().items() # becomes
UndefinedSilently().u''() # from UndefinedSilently.__getattr__
```

If you want to be able to go deeper than one level you can create a class that returns itself for every access attempt except `__str__` and `__unicode__`.

```
def silently(*args, **kwargs):
    return u''

return_new = lambda *args, **kwargs: UndefinedSilently()

class UndefinedSilently(Undefined):
    __unicode__ = silently
    __str__ = silently
    __call__ = return_new
    __getattr__ = return_new
```

Comment: great answer but, you have a syntax error: the 'return' in lambda is not necessary: `return_new = lambda *args, **kwargs: UndefinedSilently()`

Comment: I forgot to say that I prefered to create a method `def self(_self):return _self`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it addresses a relevant issue. I revive/answer this to assist others with reference to **Django 3.1/3.2/4.0**:

1. Go to your `settings.py`.
2. Add in 'OPTIONS' the following:

   ```
   'undefined': jinja2.Undefined
   ```
3. With this, undefined variables will not appear when rendered, i.e. be 'silent'. The full code should look something like this:

   ```py
   {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
       'DIRS': [
           BASE_DIR / 'templates-jinja2'
       ],
       'APP_DIRS': True,
       'OPTIONS': {
           'environment': 'config.jinja2.environment',
           'context_processors': [],
           'undefined': jinja2.DebugUndefined

       },
   },
   ```
4. Alternatively, you can use `DebugUndefined` to see undefined variables, or `'StrictUndefined'` to raise exceptions where undefined variables are used.