# Jinja2 ignore UndefinedErrors for objects that aren't found

Tags: python, jinja2

I switched to Jinja from Django but a lot of my templates broke when referencing

```
 {{ entity.property }}
```

if entity is not defined. Is there away to ignore the UndefinedErrors in certain situations, Otherwise I'll have to add in a lot of

```
 {% if entity %}{{ entity.property }}{% endif %}
```

wrappers.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jinja2 actually uses a special class for undefined entities.  You can subclass this [`Undefined`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#undefined-types) class from Jinja2 to include `__getattr__` and other [attribute accessors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) that you want to be able to use even on undefined entities and have them return a blank unicode string (for example).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182498/jinja2-how-to-make-it-fail-silently-like-djangotemplate/6192308

Comment: `__getattr__` is never called on Undefined, if the value is an empty string.

Comment: @wvxvw - the point was that you could create an `Undefined` subclass that would return *itself* for every attribute accessor except for `__unicode__` / `__str__` - and when it was coerced to a string it would return the empty string `''`.  I didn't mean that you could make indexing into a *bound* Jinja variable which happened to be an empty string work.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 9):

Building off of Sean's excellent and helpful answer, I did the following:

```
from jinja2 import Undefined
import logging

class SilentUndefined(Undefined):
    '''
    Dont break pageloads because vars arent there!
    '''
    def _fail_with_undefined_error(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.exception('JINJA2: something was undefined!')
        return None
```

and then `env = Environment(undefined=SilentUndefined)` where I was calling that.

In the django_jinja library, which I use, the above is in `base.py` and is actually a modification of `initial_params`

Comment: If you want to have your class return something other than an empty string, you can override the __str__ method, like: 
`def __str__(self):
    return f'[NOT FOUND:{self_undefined_name}'
`
_undefined_name is the name of the key that it was trying to look up. There is also a ready-made class in Jinja for this, called DebugUndefined, but it doesn't give you this flexibility in what string it returns.

Answer (score 7):

I built on @rattray's answer above:

```
from jinja2 import Undefined, Template

class SilentUndefined(Undefined):
    def _fail_with_undefined_error(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return ''
```

Then used it with template string:

```
person_dict = {'first_name': 'Frank', 'last_name': 'Hervert'}
t2 = Template("{{ person1.last_name }}, {{ person.last_name }}", undefined=SilentUndefined)

print t2.render({'person': person_dict})                                                                         
# ', Hervert'
```

I needed to ignore the errors when rendering a Template from string directly instead of using Environment.

Answer (score 6):

I also needed to reset the class's magic methods to make object attributes etc work correctly. Adding to @rattray --

```
from jinja2 import Undefined, Template

class SilentUndefined(Undefined):
    def _fail_with_undefined_error(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return ''

    __add__ = __radd__ = __mul__ = __rmul__ = __div__ = __rdiv__ = \
        __truediv__ = __rtruediv__ = __floordiv__ = __rfloordiv__ = \
        __mod__ = __rmod__ = __pos__ = __neg__ = __call__ = \
        __getitem__ = __lt__ = __le__ = __gt__ = __ge__ = __int__ = \
        __float__ = __complex__ = __pow__ = __rpow__ = \
        _fail_with_undefined_error
```

It'd make sense to be a jinja setting. A lot of people would be coming from django templates which are silent by default.

Comment: This is the only variant of SilentUndefined which worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Also was looking for a solution and used @s29 SilentUndefined class, but I`ve caught "'str' object is not callable" error when undefined variable was tried to be called, so this is my workaround, it could be helpful for someone

```
class SilentUndefined(Undefined):

    def _fail_with_undefined_error(self, *args, **kwargs):
        class EmptyString(str):
            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return ''
        return EmptyString()

 __add__ = __radd__ = __mul__ = __rmul__ = __div__ = __rdiv__ = \
    __truediv__ = __rtruediv__ = __floordiv__ = __rfloordiv__ = \
    __mod__ = __rmod__ = __pos__ = __neg__ = __call__ = \
    __getitem__ = __lt__ = __le__ = __gt__ = __ge__ = __int__ = \
    __float__ = __complex__ = __pow__ = __rpow__ = \
    _fail_with_undefined_error
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jinja2 within ansible, there's a setting that lets you specify the default behaviour for a missing variable. In ansible.cfg:

```
[Defaults]
error_on_undefined_vars=False
```

Note that this, and the defaults filter, only works if what's missing is at the end of a dot path. Eg: `{{ a.b.c }}` will work if 'c' is missing, but will still fail with a KeyError if 'b' is missing.